# Google Calendar API doesn't work with a calendars from Google Apps for Work

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I'm using the Google Calendar API to synchronise calendars with Google Calendar.

It work fine with a normal Google account, but I can't get it to work with a `Google for Work` account.

I basically ask credential to create a new calendar and then define myself as an owner of the calendar to be able to update it in the future. This is working for both types of account, but when I try to add new events, with the `Google for Work` account, I get a 403 Forbidden error.

Since it's working fine for the normal Google account, I assume there is a security setting somewhere which prevent me to create events but I can find which one.

I tried to add my client ID and the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` in the Admin console of the Google for Work account but it as no effect.

Comment: It seems related to "External Sharing options for primary calendars" in the Admin account: https://support.google.com/a/answer/60765?hl=en

Comment: Indeed, it is exactly that. Could you answer the question so I can accept it ? Also, notification channels doesn't seem to work, any idea if there is also something to configure in the admin console for this ?

Comment: Glad it worked! For push, have you followed all the instructions in here? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push I propose you create a separate question with more details for that.

Comment: Yeah, I have push working on normal Google accounts but not in Google for work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"External Sharing options for primary calendars" controls in what way accounts outside the domain can access calendars within the domain. The setting is in the Admin console: support.google.com/a/answer/60765?hl=en